# Removing/renaming app_offline.htm causing 100% CPU usage

Tags: sql-server, performance

I often use app_offline.htm to show a message to users when I'm making changes to the site. My workflow is as such:

1. Rename OFF_app_offline.htm -> app_offline.htm
2. Make changes to website
3. Rename app_offline.htm -> OFF_app_offline.htm

Sometimes when I do step 3, the website comes back online, but the server is suddenly using 100% of the CPU and thus runs incredibly slowly and `iisreset.exe` needs to be run to get it running normally again. The two processes that use around 50% CPU each are `w3wp.exe` and `sqlservr.exe`. Usually the server sits at around 20% CPU usage.

I don't have the rights on my VPS account to run `iisreset.exe` so I have to contact my hosting providers and get them to do it. This is time consuming and meanwhile, my website users get frustrated with slow speeds!

Why is this happening? What can I do to stop it happening? Are there any settings on the server I can suggest that would stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you remove the app_offline.htm file, the next request into the application will cause ASP.NET to load the application and app-domain again, and life will continue along as normal.

It should heat the cpu during a perioud but not for a long time.

Try increasing the worker processes for this aplication pool for this application on IIS so not only one w3wp.exe process
assumes all the load.

**EDIT:**

Try changing your session configuration. I don't know what storage option are you using for
your session states, (I guess sql-state due to the sql server process load) but maybe you could try to change it:

Check the following link:

[Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Each application on my VPS is running under a dedicated AppPool but I haven't heard of using multiple app pools for a single application before. Is there any information you can link to about this? Or do you mean more worker processes for the one AppPool?

Comment: YEah, I mean assigning more worker processes to the application pool. Have you tried it?

Comment: I will definitely try it out, though from what I read, I'll need to do some testing around session concerns, etc. The application is .NET MVC so I shouldn't think I'd have any problems, but you never know! Thanks heaps for your answer - I'll mark it as accepted if my testing turns out to make a positive difference :)

Comment: How are you session saving? inProc, state or sql server?

Comment: Ok lets try it. It's important to know too as you say, what kind of session storage are you using, maybe it could be your problem because when you rename app_offline all that stuff is triggered. I updated my answer with information of all available session states in case you need them. But you are telling your sql server process loads the cpu so I guess you are in sql-state

Comment: `InProc` I guess if that's the default - I haven't specified anything in my `web.config`. Though my app is more or less stateless (so I wouldn't expect this to affect anything), I still need to check it.